# Need help with parametrization and finding $\int_{K,+}(x+\sqrt{z})dy+(x+\sqrt{y})dy$ where $K=\{(x,y,z):y+z=5x^2,yz=4x^2,y\leq z\,-2\leq x\leq 1\}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, differential-forms, parametrization

Find $$\int_{K,+}(x+\sqrt{z})dy+(x+\sqrt{y})dy$$ where $K=\{(x,y,z):y+z=5x^2,yz=4x^2,y\leq z\,-2\leq x\leq 1\}$

$(K,+)$ means that we start from point $(-2,4,16)$ and end in $(1,1,4)$.

I do not know how to solve it. I believe that first we need to find parametrization of curve $K$. But I do not why I have problem with this. I cannot find any sensible parametrization. I suspect, although I am not sure, that with parametrization I would know how to end this. So I will be thankful for any hints.

Comment: I have written (and taught) numerous challenging vector calculus problems. This one wins the prize for the most outrageously complicated (and to what end?). To boot, something's very wrong. Those points don't satisfy the conditions defining $K$. The final inequality is false for both points. Can you double-check what's going on? ... Using the first two equations, we can in fact solve for (two possible) parametrizations in terms of $x$.

Comment: However,  let me comment that $\int x\,dy + (x+\sqrt y)\,dy$ is path-independent, but we do need a path for $\int\sqrt z\,dy$. This looks outrageously horrid, but note that $z=4x^2/y$ (since we're on one of the surfaces), so this becomes $\int 2x/\sqrt y\,dy$, which may be marginally better. Altogether, yuck! And I have no idea what to do with that third constraint.